# enable secure site only on certain pages

Tags: 6

I am sending out user generation emails, but users can not access their one time login because of secure site  from this link i see something about "Bypass Login Filter Page" and an option to set secure site login exceptions on certain pages but I can not find that anywhere.

http://drupal.org/node/98514

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two options, but there could be more (quotes included are from their project pages):

1. [Secure Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/securepages):

   > A small process which will redirect the required pages to a SSL version of the page.
2. [Context SSL](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_ssl):

   > Allow site administrators to make sure certain sections of their sites are always accessed through SSL.
   >
   > This module adds a reaction plugin to the Context module and thus benefits from all the flexibility that the Context module provides.

Comment: I don't mean SSL i mean behind http login